# Add user to Yammer group, using API

Tags: yammer

I want to add a user to a group through the API. The proper endpoint should be:

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/group_settings/process_additions , but keep getting a 404.

I found this, describing my exact problem, but no answers:

I want to join users except current login to yammer group. or I want to invite them to join yammer group using javascript sdk by yammer. I found one way of doing that by following

Makes a POST to: same call as above

```
id: GROUP_ID

invites[ids][]: USER_ID

invites[emails][addresses]:
```

I don't know how to call it. I tried to call that URI but it gave me error like

`"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"` can any one tell me how to pass that data to request call ?

So: How to call https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/group_settings/process_additions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is an `authenticity_token` param missing in your URL. You must supply that parameter.

This URL works, but note that it is not documented / supported, and could potentially change at any time:

> https://www.yammer.com/insert_yammer_network_name/group_settings/process_additions/isert_groupID.json?id=isert_groupID&invites[ids][]=&invites[emails][addresses]=insert_email@domain.com&auto_add_invitees=true&authenticity_token=insert_oauth-token

Modify the above format with your details, copy it into a browser URL, hit enter, and you should get the following response `{"status":"ok"}`, or `{"already_member":"true"}` if the the user is already a member of the group.

Note that you can't make REST calls to https://www.yammer.com/* as it will result to CORS error. Use https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/ as your base URL instead.

===========================

The above solution is no longer valid. Use the [impersonation method](http://blogs.technet.com/b/israelo/archive/2015/07/31/yammer-restful-api-how-to-bulk-add-members-to-a-group.aspx) instead as it is supported/documented by yammer.

Comment: This is not a supported API and could change at any time. Only use documented APIs from developer.yammer.com.